# Getting the wrong format from grep

Tags: r

I have a question regarding the "grep" command from the dplyr package. I am trying to ascertain the position of a variable in a particular dataframe. I tried the following code:

```
coord.plot <- data.frame(getis.edu2=c(1:3),ID=c(1:3))
fill <- grep("getis.edu2",colnames(coord.plot))
```

Here is "getis.edu2" some string variable (later I want to replace this term with a variable containing the string. coord.plot is a normal dataframe, where one colname is "getis.edu2".

As long as I am not trying to store the position variable in the "fill" variable everything works perfect. R' gives me this output:

```
> grep("getis.edu2",colnames(coord.plot))
[1] 1
```

But the "fill" variable contains something like "1L". Why does this happen?

I already realized that I can easily convert this with "as.numeric".

Comment: Grep doesn't come from dplyr. And please make your example reproducible.

Comment: Oh you're right. Always thought it comes with the dplyr package. I restored the post, so now the code is reproducible.

Comment: When I run your code, I just get 1, and `typeof(fill)` results in `integer`.

Comment: Then RStudio is displaying it odd in the global environment. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: `1L` means it's an integer.